# Trying to change multiple values in cells

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Okay this is going to be a little hard to explain but I will try. I'm trying to make a string variable in excel that when I change the value in that cell it'll also change values if it is present in other cells. For example.

A1: happy

A2: www.anexample.com/happy

A3: www.anexample2/pleasehelp/happy.

So basically I want to change the value in A1 and if I change the value from "happy" to "sad" anywhere there is a "happy" value it'll turn into a "sad" value. So the final result will look like this.

A1: sad

A2: www.anexample.com/sad

A3: www.anexample2/pleasehelp/sad.

Estienally I want A1 to be a dynamic variable that when I change it'll change when it repeats in other cells where it is present. Hopefully this question is not too convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

Find & replace with the string linked to your cell rather than hard coded as below.

```
Sub Macro2()
 Cells.Replace What:="sad", Replacement:="happy", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is probably a better way to do this but what you are trying to achieve can be done by concatinating cell values.

By using the functions below in cell A2 and A3 you can change the value of A1 to sad and it will change in A2 and A3.

What cell will look like
A1: happy

A2: www.anexample.com/happy

A3: www.anexample2/pleasehelp/happy

The function for concatination

A2: =CONCATENATE("www.anexample.com/",A1)

A3: =CONCATENATE("www.anexample.com/pleasehelp/",A1)

Comment: Alternatively, `&` operator should be more efficient than `CONCATENATE` function.